# Are called HOC equivalent to regular components for purposes of hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So there are two possible ways to use React hooks:

1. directly

```js
const Signup = props => {
  const [onSubmit, {data}] = useMutation (SIGNUP_GQL)
  return (
    ...
  )
}
export default Signup
```

2. in a HOC

```
const withMutation = gql => C => props => {
   const [onSubmit, {data}] = useMutation (SIGNUP_GQL)
   return <C onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
}

const Signup = ({onSubmit, data}) => (
  ...
)
export default withMutation (SIGNUP_GQL) (Signup)
```

I prefer the second pattern. Before I structure my whole app this way, I'd like to make sure it's ok. In particular, whether the two patterns are fundamentally equivalent (regardless of the implementation), and if not, whether the implementation has full support using hooks in HOCs.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One of the main purpose of HOC is to be able to create reusable logic, and inject them to any components with ease. When there were no hooks, the only other feasible way to do this is via render props pattern.

With hooks, you can now do MOST of what you need to do with HOC. Even all the popular react libraries with complex logic can be refactored to use hooks instead. Examples are: `react-apollo`,  `react-router`, etc.

In most cases, hooks should have lower overhead compared to HOC, making it more performant. [Reference](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/this-benchmark-is-indeed-flawed-c3d6b5b6f97f)

Also, by writing your components as functions, you are helping minifier to better minify your code, resulting in smaller bundles, which is also a good thing. [Reference](https://medium.com/@jackyef/react-hooks-why-we-should-embrace-it-86e408663ad6)

BUT, that is not to say that class components are no longer useful. There are still some cases that are not possible currently with hooks, such as doing something like `componentDidCatch`, `getDerivedStateFromProps`, etc. But in most cases, hooks + function components should be sufficient.

Comment: sry for downvoting your answer, but it doesn't answer any part of the question. I'm not asking HOC or Class Components vs hooks, rather the possibility to use hooks in HOC's. On a stylistic point, I personally prefer the latter approach. It's even less code! 4 vs. 7 LOC marginally. (You write your HOC just once, so that's a fixed cost ;)

Comment: It does answer your question, by explaining the difference between them. Which is to say, they are not equivalent. They can achieve the same purpose yes, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: Another useful reference is to see how `react-apollo@3` works. They structured their package into multiple packages, such as `@apollo/react-hooks` and `@apollo/react-hoc`. What `@apollo/react-hoc` does under the hood is basically the same with what you are doing, which is wrapping over `@apollo/react-hooks`. The reason for this is, if you can use only hooks, the bundle will be smaller. Reference: https://blog.apollographql.com/apollo-client-now-with-react-hooks-676d116eeae2

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.

Your first answer explained that HOCs and hooks are not equivalent. But the second example uses hooks too. So maybe to put it more specifically, it's hooks vs HOCs + hooks..